# Laravel Validation The cover image must be an image problem

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am getting this error message for my code.. I can't figure out why it is showing me this
Blade Template file :

```
    <div class="well" style="font-family:arial;">
        <div class="well-body">
            <form class="POST" action="/admin-panel/shows/store" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th>Show Name</th>
                    <th>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="e.g, Avengers"/>
                    </div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Cover Image</th>
                    <th>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @csrf
                            <input id="cover_image" type="file" name="cover_image">
                        </div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-center">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller File :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name' => 'required | max:140',
        'plot' => 'required',
        'cover_image' => 'image | required | max:1999'

    ]);
    -----Rest of the code ---
}
```

Also I want to add the fact, a similar stuff for post creating works fine. And I can differentiate these two code with them. They look identical. Can writting action="/admin-panel/shows/store" this would be a problem?

dd($request->input('cover_image') ss:
[image]

dd($request->file('cover_image')) ss:
[image]

Update : I wasn't doing routing properly.

Comment: I'd reverse the order of rules for `cover_image`, and remove the spaces: `'cover_image' => 'required|image|max:1999'`. Also, make sure you're actually uploading an image (`png`, `jpg`, etc). Also no, `action="/admin-panel/shows/store"` is not an issue if you have a route that matches `admin-panel/shows/store`. The preferred method is `action="{{ url('...') }}"` or  `action="{{ route('...') }}"`, but omitting the helpers can still work.

Comment: Changed it...but still not working...And I am uploading a .jpg file...

Comment: Hmm... Everything else looks good. `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, `type="file"` and `name="cover_image"` are all correct, and validation rule should be ok. Can you upload an image and do a `dd($request->file("cover_image")` before `$this->validate()`? Sidenote too; you have two `@csrf`, only need one. Not likely an issue, but something to fix.

Comment: Added the screenshot... It's showing the filename correctly...Also i have removed the second @csrf

Comment: Check my comment again, it's not `$request->input()`, use `$request->file()` to access files.

Comment: Its showing "null" now

Comment: Well that ain't right. It should be something like `UploadedFile {#182 ▼... }`, unless you didn't upload a file, then it would say `null`.

Comment: But I am uploading a file [profileFaker.jpg]. What can be the reason that it's not receiving the file? $request->input() is getting the filename correctly

Comment: I am currently unable to replicate your issue. `$request->input("cover_image")` for me is always `null` (as it should be), but `$request->file("cover_image")` shows `UploadedFile { ... }` when I upload one (again, as it should). Did you post your complete form? Is there another `<input>` with the same `name="cover_image"`? Is it an ajax request? Etc.

Comment: after using action="{{route('shows.store')}}" I am getting Uploaded File{.....} ...BTW thanks for pointing out this...